# What is the biological name of this plant?

Tags: botany

[image]
The plant was observed in a rural area near Digha.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Ageratum conyzoides](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ageratum_conyzoides), a flower of Asteraceae family.

The common Bengali name of this plant is [Uchunti](http://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Goat%20Weed.html).

Other than this purple colour a white colour of this flower is also observed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Ayandip If the question has been correctly addressed you can **accept** the answer by clicking on the tick under the downvote arrow.Also you can  upvote it.